# Jquery property disable

Tags: jquery

Is there any property in jquery to help me check if a txtbox is disabled? and it lets me compare through an if statement?

for example:

```
 if ($('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox3'). == "false")
 {

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :disabled selector.

Try:

```
 if ($('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox3').is(":disabled"))  
 {    
 }
```

or

```
 if ($('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox3:disabled').length)  
 {    
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

The [:disabled](http://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/) selector was designed to do just that:

```
if ($("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox3").is(":disabled")) {
    // Text box is disabled.
}
```

If you're using jQuery 1.6 or higher, it's also safe to access the boolean DOM property with [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```
if ($("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox3").prop("disabled")) {
    // Text box is disabled.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:enabled` pseudoselector.

http://api.jquery.com/enabled-selector/

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('#MyInput').attr('disabled') == 'disabled'){
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox3").is(":enabled")
```

will return the value of enabled status.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) if you are using jQuery 1.6+.

```
if ($('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox3').prop('disabled')) { ... }
```